# Power Shell Output Re-Filter | Get-CalendarProcessing

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, outlook-2010, exchange-management-shell

I'm trying to write a script that shows resource delegates in Outlook 2010 mailboxes. The code for this is:

```
input > Get-CalendarProcessing -Identity $Alias | where {$_.ResourceDelegates -ne "{}"} | ft *
```

The output important to me is the Resource and Mailbox identity.

```
ResourceDelegates                   : {TEST/A/A Usr, TEST/A/Kelly Besant, TEST/A/A Usr,
Identity                            : TEST/A/A Usr
```

I need the names in a standard format and not in the canonical format, how can I convert them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the canonical name with get-recipeint to resolve to Name, DisplayName, or DN:

```
Get-CalendarProcessing -Identity $Alias |
 where {$_.ResourceDelegates -ne "{}"} | 
 select -ExpandProperty ResourceDelegates |
 get-recipient |
 select -ExpandProperty Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Each ResourceDelegates or Identity object has a name property (EMS required):

```
$Identity = @{n='Identity';e={$_.Identity.Name}}
$ResourceDelegates = @{n='ResourceDelegates';e={$_.ResourceDelegates | foreach {$_.Name}}}
Get-CalendarProcessing $alias| Select-Object $Identity,$ResourceDelegates
```

Comment: If you're using implicit remoting, the identity propery just comes back as a string.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've added a "required".